# I'm doing something stupid.... perl matrix creation.... counting improperly or testing improperly

Tags: perl

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @range = (1..16);
@range = shuffle(@range);

# lets make a cool grid
my $count = 0;
my $row = 1;
my $grid = {};
my @tmp;

my $c = @range;

print "Found: $c entries.\n\n";

foreach my $num ( @range ) {
   if ( $count == 4 ) {
        $grid->{$row} = [@tmp];
        $row++;
        $count = 0;
        undef @tmp;
        next;
   }
   $count++;
   push @tmp, $num;
   print "ROW $row, COUNT: $count\n";

}

print Dumper $grid;
```

Output:

```
Found: 16 entries.

ROW 1, COUNT: 1
ROW 1, COUNT: 2
ROW 1, COUNT: 3
ROW 1, COUNT: 4
ROW 2, COUNT: 1
ROW 2, COUNT: 2
ROW 2, COUNT: 3
ROW 2, COUNT: 4
ROW 3, COUNT: 1
ROW 3, COUNT: 2
ROW 3, COUNT: 3
ROW 3, COUNT: 4
ROW 4, COUNT: 1
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => [
                   9,
                   12,
                   4,
                   2
                 ],
          '3' => [
                   14,
                   3,
                   1,
                   6
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   15,
                   7,
                   16,
                   5
                 ]
        };
```

I'm looking for a 4 by 4 matrix

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Your question is a bit vague!

Comment: I am looking for hashref w/ 4 keys containing an array of 4 values

Comment: Is this the best title for describing your problem?  Could you please consider rephrasing it?

Comment: sorry I'm just a "bit" intoxicated modified

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of changes and you've got it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @range = (1..16);
@range = shuffle(@range);

# lets make a cool grid
my $count = 0;
my $row = 0;     # start this at 0 instead of 1
my $grid = [];   # make this an array instead of a hash
my @tmp;

my $c = @range;

print "Found: $c entries.\n\n";

foreach my $num ( @range ) {
   $count++;
   push @tmp, $num;
   print "ROW $row, COUNT: $count\n";
   if ( $count == 4 ) {                  # move this to the end of the loop
        $grid->[$row] = [@tmp];
        $row++;
        $count = 0;
        undef @tmp;
   }
}

print Dumper $grid;
```

Partial output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            8,
            3,
            12,
            4
          ],
          [
            1,
            10,
            14,
            15
          ],
          [
            6,
            16,
            2,
            5
          ],
          [
            7,
            13,
            11,
            9
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a little simpler using `splice`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @array = shuffle(1..16);

my @AofA;
while (@array) {
    push @AofA, [splice @array, 0, 4];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@AofA;
```

Outputs:

```
[[5, 13, 8, 4], [15, 9, 6, 3], [12, 7, 16, 14], [10, 1, 11, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding what you're after, this should do the trick:

```
my @range = (1..16);

# lets make a cool grid
my $grid = {};

for (my $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    @range = shuffle(@range);
    print qq|Doing: $i \n|;
    $grid->{$i} = [splice(@range,0,4)]; # get the first 4 element, as we have it shuffled now
}

print Dumper $grid;
```

The idea is, that you just loop through 4 values (1-4), and then for each of those, `shuffle` the array, and finally grab the first 4 elements now in the array. This should give you 4 random picks from the range you provided, whilst still being nice and effecient :)

Comment: Why the negative? My answer works perfectly - and is far more efficient / cleaner than the original code!

Comment: I didn't vote against you, but the reason for the negative is probably because you repeat the numbers.

Comment: @Miller - thanks for the reply. I didn't relalise thats what he wanted (I replied right away, before he had tweaked the question). I've updated my code, so that it uses `splice()` now, so the numbers are not-reused.